# MS Access Percentage conversion from Integer

Tags: ms-access, type-conversion, percentage

On my Access database, I have converted integer values to percentages but the percentages are not equal to 100%. Are there any methods on Access that would allow me to show percentage values that add up to 100%?

This is my query which has two fields that are 60% and 20%.

[image: Query Design View]

[image: Query]

Comment: Wouldnt a percentage be the number  of `[good_responses]` divided by the total number of responses which is `([good_responses]+[Bad_Responses])`?

Comment: Do you mean this?                                                                            Expr2: Sum([Good_Responses]/([Good_Responses])+[Bad_Responses])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the percentage of the good response =>
>   `([Good_Responses]/([Good_Responses])+[Bad_Responses])*100`
>
> And the percentage of the bad response =>
>   `([Bad_Responses]/([Good_Responses])+[Bad_Responses])*100`

lets say you've got about 30 hits, 12 were Good & the remaining 18 were bad.

> (12/30) *100 = 40
>
> (18/30) *100 = 60

which would make up for the total 100% you are looking for.
i hope this was what you were looking for.

Edit

Just recreated the situation & it's working fine. 
first get the `sum` of both fields & from the resulting query create a query that will calculate the percentage using the formula above. i have added screenshots.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Beat me to it. To get a "true" percentage, you would need to take the "response"  you want and divide it by the total "responses" (Bad + Good), then * 100. Like shown in @Benion's example above.

Comment: @benion, I tried adding in your code but for Good Responses, I am now getting 30000.00% and 23333.33% for Bad Responses. I used Sum before I added in your code.

Comment: @Benion, for example:` Good Responses: Sum([Good_Responses]/[Good_Responses]+[Bad_Responses])*100`

Comment: What are the actual values of your Good & Bad Response fields? & why are you using `Sum`

Comment: @Benion, for the good responses I am getting 30000.00% and for bad responses I am getting 23333.33%. I tried executing it without Sum but Access won't allow me unless I include an aggregate function.

Comment: @JonathanHenry Your order of operations will do the division first. Good/Good will get you 1 every time. You need to add the divisor first, then divide.

Comment: @Huntdogg, like this? `Good Responses: Sum([Good_Responses]+[Bad_Responses]/[Good_Responses])*100`

Comment: Correct math structure would require this: [Good Responses]/([Good Responses]+[Bad Responses])*100

Comment: i have edited the Answer with screenshot images, take a look

Comment: @Benion, yeah it's working now. Thank you for all your help.